# Docusign API sets recipientSuppliesTabs to always true

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using this gem (https://github.com/jondkinney/docusign_rest) to make calls to the Docusign API. 
On my Docusign account I have a template where the roles are: Buyer, Developer.

When I use the API to create an envelope from that template, recipientSuppliesTabs is always set to true. Even if I explicitly set it to false.

If anybody can point me to the right direction, that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: That is not an officially supported docusign package, unfortunately DocuSign doesn't currently have a Ruby SDK. You'll have to reach out to the owner of that package to ask for a fix if there's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The docusign_rest gem doesn't explicitly set that field's value.  On the other hand, it doesn't pass a `false` value through if you pass it as an option.  So if the "create envelope" API endpoint is defaulting to `true` for that value, there's no way to set it to `false`.

If you still would find this useful, please [file an issue on the docusign_rest project](https://github.com/jondkinney/docusign_rest/issues) and I'll add it, thanks!